# Error in dbEscapeStrings/concerto.updateState [concerto platform]

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql, ubuntu-15.04

I have installed concerto platform in my computer (Ubuntu 15.04). I am trying to run a simple test but it stops when the  second html template is supposed to appear (I've attached the output below).

I have tried to upload RMySQL to current version 10.7 and,   after that,restarting apache2 but it is still not working.

Any idea of what can be wrong?

Thanks in advance

[image: dbEScapeStrings]

Answer (score 0):

Finally a friend had helped me.

If I give full rights to /var/www/concerto/data/1 the problem is solved.

I think something went wrong in my concerto installation when i gave rights to /var/www/concerto/data.

Thank you anyway,

A